# How to stop jQuery element from being cloned when dragged?

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

I'm a designer who's relatively new to jQuery, so please bear with me!

I've put together a database query creation program based on a jQuery shopping cart model.

Essentally, the user drags field names and boolean operators to a "cart" area and drops them, thereby creating a list of elements that can be converted to a comma-separated string and saved as a query. The dragged element is actually a clone of the orignal.

The basic sequence of elements in the cart area is:

```
field name, boolean, constant or field name, optional and/or, etc.
```

so that you might end up with a string like this:

```
product,equals,hardcoverbook,and,pubdate,lessthan,12/31/13
```

which is the same as:

```
Product = HardcoverBook AND PubDate < 123113
```

In order to keep a logical sequence in the query creation area, all fields are generally disabled after a field is dropped, thereby restricting the user to dragging an operator; and all boolean operators are disabled after a boolean operator is dropped. Otherwise, you could end up with a nonsensical query, for example:

```
has,greaterthan,hardcoverbook,newspaper
```

When a field or operator is dropped, it should be able to be deleted by dragging it to a Trash div.

At the same time, the previous element should no longer be deletable – otherwise, a user could wreak havoc with the query being created by randomly deleting elements.

For example, where "el" is a field name being dragged and dropped, a "deletable" class is added to it as part of the drop function and removed from the previous list elemet:

```
$(el).addClass("deletable").prev('li').removeClass("deletable");
```

This part is working fine, i.e., the last-dropped  list element can be deleted and previous list elements cannot be deleted.

The problem I'm having is that, if a user drags a list element that's been dropped to the query creation area [the "cart"] a clone of that list element is created. Then, that clone can be dragged, thereby creating another clone.

Since the original drop event appends a comma after a dropped field name or operator [in order to end up with a comma-separated string], I think dragging the dropped field is recreating the initial drop event? You can see that because a comma is being appended to each clone every time the drag is stopped.

I can stop dropped elements from being cloned when they're dragged if I make the "cart" div not sortable – but then I can't drag them to the trash:

```
$("#cartInv ol").droppable({
    accept: "(#catalogProd2 li,#boolean li,#and_or li,#constant li)",
    accept: ":not(#catalogInv li,#catalogProd2 li,#catalogRB1 li,#catalogRB2 li)"
    }
    ).sortable("disable");
```

So – sorry for my long-windedness – to sum up, I need help with preventing a dropped element from being cloned when it's dragged while keeping it "deletable" so it can be dragged to the trash.

I have a complete working version of the page that shows the cloning problem:

http://tinyurl.com/nr4tpbp

A second page shows the behavior when the 'cart'' is made not sortable – the element can't be dragged and therefore isn't cloned, but it also can't be dragged to the trash:

http://tinyurl.com/qcawmax

Any help much appreciated!